# In-class initialization of lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

The following code

```
struct X
{
    static constexpr auto lambda=[](int* t)->int&{ return *t; };
};

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int* p=&x;

    return X::lambda(p);
}
```

produces this error:

```
y.cc:3:24: error: ‘constexpr const X::<lambda(int*)> X::lambda’, declared using local type ‘const X::<lambda(int*)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
  static constexpr auto lambda=[](int* t)->int&{ return *t; };
```

I am not sure if one can in-class initialize a lambda. In any case, I do not understand this particular error message since `lambda` clearly is defined.

Comment: Try [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a0fe9acb1fadf2b).

Comment: Static member declarations are not definitions in C++ (although static `constexpr` declarations *are* definitions in C++17).

Comment: This is a moot problem: the initializer is only allowed on `constexpr` static data members, but lambdas can only be constant expressions in C++17 ([P0170R1](http://wg21.link/p0170r1)). But in C++17, `constexpr` static data member declarations are also definitions ([P0386R2](http://wg21.link/p0386r2)), so the problem doesn't exist in any of the revisions of the C++ standard. It's only visible in some partial implementation you are using.

Comment: Have a look at the motivation section of this document: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4487.pdf  => lambdas are indeed not allowed to be constexprs before C++17

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the explanation. It can be fixed by adding an explicit definition `constexpr decltype(X::lambda) X::lambda;` This was suggested by an answer that since has been deleted for some reason...

Comment: @TFM: Well, the reason is in my two comments: the "answer" didn't actually appertain to any C++ language standard.